# Javascript not working after rendering partial rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

```
<% if @questions_counter == 2 %>
  <% if @finish_btn == 0 %>
    $("#initial-question-frame").fadeOut('fast');
    $("#next-question-frame").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => "question", :locals => {:question => @question})) %>").fadeIn();
  <% else %>
    $("#initial-question-frame").fadeOut('fast');
    $("#next-question-frame").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => "question", :locals => {:question => @question})) %>").fadeIn();
    $("#process-question-submit").fadeOut();
    $("#finish-test-button").fadeIn();
  <% end %>
```

The problem is, when `@finish_btn = 1`,

`#process-question-submit` is not fading out, 
nor the `#finish-test-button` fades in

Note: that both buttons are inside the rendered partial above.

Answer (score 1):

This is because, `render` a `partial` just insert the HTML to the view before `javascript` run by the browser. In that case, `DOM` event handler goes to inactive.

To resolved this, just bind your `DOM` inside the `document` and it will keep your handler still active even after `ajax` call.

```
<% if @questions_counter == 2 %>
  <% if @finish_btn == 0 %>
    $("#initial-question-frame").fadeOut('fast');
    $("#next-question-frame").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => "question", :locals => {:question => @question})) %>").fadeIn();
  <% else %>
    $("#initial-question-frame").fadeOut('fast');
    $("#next-question-frame").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => "question", :locals => {:question => @question})) %>").fadeIn();

    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#process-question-submit").fadeOut();
      $("#finish-test-button").fadeIn();
    });
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
var _question = "<%= j render(:partial => 'question', :locals => {:question => @question}) %>";
$('#next-question-frame').empty();
$('#next-question-frame').append(_question);
$("#process-question-submit").fadeOut();
$("#finish-test-button").fadeIn();
```

Your Javascript should work, so it seems the partial might not be rendering properly. If this doesn't work, you might try troubleshooting by just getting the partial to show first with `#finish-test-button {display: block;}` to make sure it's showing up.

If none of that works, try putting the Javascript to fade in the button inside the partial.

Comment: actually the partial does get rendered its just the jquery does not work after that. and this is on subsequent partial renderings, because i call the partial rendering many times each time changing the @question variable.Will try those though thanks